# How to add my own picture to android background

Tags: java, android, android-studio, background

How to add my own picture to android app background(not app icon background) 
i can not drag my file(.png) to the drawable if i use image asset the picture will become icon but i want full background

now i can add but when i use the app it will show the error

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

Comment: You should just be able to set the image in the theme as `windowBackground` and it should become the default background for all your activities (just make sure to not have a background colour in the layouts). This will result in some skewing issues unless you provide images for all screen sizes and aspect rations. Are you bundling the image or trying to load it from the web?

Comment: bundling and where to set the windowbackground

Comment: i find it but the all xml back ground will be that picture i want some are white

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) Convert your png file into 9 patch(so the image stretches as per
>   the device screen).  Or convert the image into SVG image.
>   2) Copy and paste those generates 9-patch images
>   into the corresponding drawable folders as per the size.
>   3) Add
>   the following tag in the xml's parent layout:

```
android:background="@drawable/nameOfMyImage"
```

Answer (score 0):

conver picture in 9 patch and copy that image and  in to drawable folder

in layout xml file addd this
android:background=@drawable/name of your picture